# Is there a way to join the below 2 queries

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I'm trying to join the below 2 queries.. though both of the below queries use the same tables, I'm unable to get the correct result..

In this query I'm checking for entries present in table 1 which would satisfy the condition m1.condition is 1, and for that entry a query is made to table 2 where even after 5 minutes there is no entry in table 2,then get the count of that entries.

The date check you see for 30 min is to get all the entries in table which are processed half an hour before.

```
SELECT count(*) AS TOTALCOUNT, 
       SELECT TO_CHAR(amount, '$999,999,999,999,999.99') AS TOTALVALUE 
from table1 m1 
LEFT JOIN table2 m ON m.id=m1.id 
where m1.condition='1' 
  and amount BETWEEN 1000 and 25000 
  and (m1.DATE <= (select to_char((select systimestamp - interval '0 00:05' day to minute from dual),'dd-MON-yy HH.MI.SS AM TZD') from dual)) 
  and m1.DATE <= (select to_char((select systimestamp - interval '0 00:30' day to minute from dual),'dd-MON-yy HH.MI.SS AM TZD') from dual) 
  and m1.DATE <= systimestamp
```

similarly in below query in table 2 there are some conditions.. so based on that I'm performing some actions.

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM (CASE when m.f = 'Converted' then 1 else 0 END),0) AS CCOUNT, 
       COALESCE(SUM (CASE when m.f = 'Do Not Convert' then 1 else 0 END),0) AS NCOUNT, 
       count(m. id) AS TOTALCOUNT, 
       TO_CHAR(COALESCE (SUM(CASE when m.f = 'C' then (amount) END),0), '$999,999,999,999,999.99') AS CONVERTED, 
       TO_CHAR(COALESCE (SUM(CASE when m.f = 'D' then (amount) END),0), '$999,999,999,999,999.99') AS NONCONVERTED, 
       TO_CHAR(COALESCE (SUM(CASE when m.f <> '0' then (amount) END),0), '$999,999,999,999,999.99') AS TOTAL 
FROM table1 ml 
JOIN table2 m ON m.id=ml.id 
             and amount BETWEEN 1000 and 25000 
             and m1.DATE <= (select to_char((select systimestamp - interval '0 30:00' day to minute from dual),'dd-MON-yy HH.MI.SS AM TZD') from dual) 
             and m1.DATE < systimestamp;
```

I have to combine both the above queries.. but I'm unable to do.

Comment: Read about conditional aggregation.  Also, please format your question so that others may read it.

Comment: *similarly in below query in table 2 there are some conditions.* The conditions are too different. Does a part of WHERE clause in 2nd query was lost so WHERE in 2nd become a part of joining condition?

Comment: The 5 minute condition in the first query is superfluous, because rows that are at least 30 minutes old are implicitly at least 5 minutes old. Why are you comparing `m1.DATE` with a string? What is `m1.DATE` column's datatype? Which table does column `amount` reside in?

Comment: How are the two tables related? `ON m.id=m1.id` doesn't seem to make much sense. It is unlikely the tables share the same unique ID. So, is it `ON m.id=m1.m_id` or `ON m.m1_id=m1.id`? Or, in other words: can I get more than one m row per m1 row?

Comment: amount is in table1, the conditions are not different.. in second query, I am trying to fetch rows from table1 based on a condition of decision in table2. Once there is a decision found, I will get the id of it, and then in table 1 get the corresponding values..

Comment: the id is a common factor or common column for both the tables

Comment: the queries run correctly individually fine.. when I try to combine the query 1 into query 2, I am not getting result. Like how do I handle a case where there is no entry in table 2 based on a condition in table 1, how do I combine it in the CASE

Comment: Any ideas are welcome..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real difference between filters is that `m1.condition = '1'`, so just add

```
   count(case condition when '1' then 1 end) as condition_1_totalcount, 
   sum(case condition when '1' then amount end) as condition_1_totalvalue
```

to your second query. In my short test it looks OK:

```
-- sample data
with 
  table1(id, date_, condition) as (
    select 1, date '1990-02-19', '1' from dual union all
    select 2, date '1990-02-19', '7' from dual union all
    select 3, date '1990-02-19', '1' from dual union all
    select 4, date '1990-02-19', '1' from dual ),
  table2(id, f, amount) as (
    select 1, 'C', 3000 from dual union all
    select 2, 'D', 3500 from dual union all
    select 3, 'D', 4000 from dual union all
    select 4, 'D', 5000 from dual )

-- query
select sum (case when m.f = 'Converted' then 1 else 0 end) ccount, 
       sum (case when m.f = 'Do Not Convert' then 1 else 0 end) as ncount, 
       count(m.id) as totalcount, 
       sum(case when m.f = 'C' then (amount) end) as converted, 
       sum(case when m.f = 'D' then (amount) end) as nonconverted, 
       sum(case when m.f <> '0' then (amount) end) as total,
       count(case condition when '1' then 1 end) as condition_1_totalcount, 
       sum(case condition when '1' then amount end) as condition_1_totalvalue 
  from table1 ml
  join table2 m on m.id = ml.id 
  where ml.date_ <= systimestamp - interval '30' minute
    and amount between 1000 and 25000
```

I do not fully understand why is this `5 min` part in first query. Rows older than 30 minutes are also older than 5 min, so it is superfluous as pointed in comments. And older than current timestamp. If you need to differentiate values this way you can also place this condition in `case when`s.